# Jasmin spyOn only works when spied-on function is wrapped, but not when delegated to

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

In this contrived case, I have a service that takes one dependency.  The service exposes one method that needs to call through to the dependency.

If I wrap this method call in its own function, then spyOn works as expected (`MyService1`).  However, if I delegate to this service directly, then spyOn fails (`MyService2`).

My questions are:

1. Can someone please explain this behaviour?
2. If I want to use spyOn, must I re-write all my directly delegated methods as wrappers, or is there a way around this?

Thanks.

```
describe('spyOn problem', function() {

    // wraps dependency function - can spy on
    var MyService1 = function (dependency) {
        this.continue = function() {
            dependency.nextStage();
        };
    };

    // delegates to dependecy function - cannot spy on
    var MyService2 = function (dependency) {
        this.continue = dependency.nextStage;
    };

    var dependencyMock = {
        nextStage: function () {
        }
    };

    it('should call nextStage method of MyService dependency', function () {
        var service = new MyService1(dependencyMock);
        spyOn(dependencyMock, 'nextStage'); // also tried with .andCallThrough()
        service.continue();
        expect(dependencyMock.nextStage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // Fail: "Expected spy nextStage to have been called"
    });

    it('should call nextStage method of MyService2 dependency', function () {
        var service = new MyService2(dependencyMock);
        spyOn(dependencyMock, 'nextStage');
        service.continue();
        expect(dependencyMock.nextStage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        // Pass
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jasmine Spies works on the objects, which means for `spyOn(dependencyMock, 'nextStage')`, the function `nextStage` on the object `dependencyMock` will be replaced with a jasmine spy function with this statement.

In `MyService2` test case, the spy is installed after actually assigning the function `nextStage` to `continue`, which means `continue` will refer to the actual function `nextStage` and not to spy. By modifying the test case as below, the spy will be assigned instead.

```
it('should call nextStage method of MyService2 dependency', function () {
    spyOn(dependencyMock, 'nextStage');
    var service = new MyService2(dependencyMock);
    service.continue();
    expect(dependencyMock.nextStage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // Pass
});
```

In the `MyService1` test case, even though you are calling `service.continue()`, it internally operates on 'dependencyMask` object for which spy is installed.